# Store State Per Page in session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, viewstate

In my scenario, I need to maintain state of the difference page. For example sorting, paging of the grid view. When a user navigates to another page then they come back to the gridview page. 
They will see the Grid with the same paging/sorting/filtering what they left the page before.

I found a solution about this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18445/Maintaining-State-Per-Page-in-ASP-NET-Web-Applicat

But I don't really understand the coding.

Here is the part that I don't understand?

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            PullStated();
            PageState.SetPageState(this, this.PageState);
        }

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }


 protected virtual void PullStated()
    {
    }
```

Why inside PullStated() method is empty? what is the purpose of PullStated()?

Comment: One of the misspellings in your third sentence makes me think SO may not be your most frequented website.

Comment: is better to ask direct the coder of this functionality. Personally I do not find that anywhere. Maybe have to do with the this code only.